# Android is cutting off (clipping) Arabic text in EditText and TextView

Tags: android, android-edittext, render, arabic, opentype

I have a multiline EditText, for editing Arabic text, as you can see Android cuts off some characters because they are rendered right after zero margin (adding spaces is not a solution because it's multi-line and the user changes the text by editing, adding padding and margin is not a fix too):

[image]

Comment: I'm facing the same issue here, did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to add padding correctly?
You may try this:

```
<EditText
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:paddingLeft="10dp"
     android:paddingRight="10dp" />
```

paddingLeft and paddingRight make sures that it leaves 10dp size left and right of your text inside your EditText.
Also you can may add some attributes to this EditText that I think it would be great:

```
android:gravity="center"
android:textDirection="rtl"
```

gravity="center" would make the text be centered at the center of the EditText (You may like this approach but it shouldn't be necessary to fix the above problem).
textDirection="rtl" make sures that this language is from right to left so it would be more professional to make it.
You may also try this instead of paddingLeft and paddingRight:

```
android:paddingStart="10dp"
android:paddingEnd="10dp"
```